# Chrome: Form Border Radius Different than Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, css

I have some HTML/CSS which is working perfectly in Firefox; however, in Chrome, the form/border is being squeezed! I have been playing with the code for hours to no avail. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W22DC/19/

Or if you prefer, the code is below...

The CSS:

```
.form1 input{
font-weight:normal;
font-size:100%;
border: 2px solid purple;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
-khtml-border-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px;
border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
background-color:transparent;    
padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
}
.form1 input:hover, input:focus{
border: 2px solid black;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<br />
<div class="form1" align="center"><form name="Example" action="" method="post" style="margin-bottom: 0">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="7" />
</form></div>
<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known chrome bug](http://designfestival.com/border-radius-and-inset-box-shadow-bug-solution/) on inputs and you can't have a border-radius that adds up to more than the height of the element. If you want it perfectly round then make sure the dimensions are exact.

e.g.
Code:

```
.form1 input{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:100%;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -khtml-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-color:transparent;        
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    line-height:28px;
    text-align:center;
}
    .form1 input:hover, input:focus{
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

For a 15px border-radius you need an element that must be at least 30px x 30px.

**Credit goes to [Paul](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?850589-Chrome-Form-Border-Radius-Different-than-Firefox&p=5112662&viewfull=1#post5112662).**